# Calculate coherence for non-gensim topic model

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, package, topic-modeling

I've built a topic model, with:

- **Input**: list of tokenized lists
- **Output**: a *m x t* matrix (with each cell indicating the probability of word *i* appearing in topic *k*).
- **Output**: a *k x n* matrix (with each cell indicating the probability of topic *k* in document *j*).

To find the optimal number of topics, I want to calculate the coherence for a model. However, I am only aware of `Gensim`'s `Coherencemodel`, which seems to require a Gensim model as input.

Are there any other packages/implementations that I could use to calculate the coherence of a computed topic model? Or, if it is indeed possible to use the `Coherencemodel` without inputting a LDAmodel, could someone show me how to do that?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/92364/8560

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you can do this with the Gensim package.

input_data = list of list with tokenized texts

topics = list with top N words per topic

```
import gensim.corpora as corpora
from gensim.models.coherencemodel import CoherenceModel

id2word = corpora.Dictionary(input_data)
corpus = [id2word.doc2bow(text) for text in input_data]

cm = CoherenceModel(topics=topics,texts = input_data,corpus=corpus, dictionary=id2word, coherence='c_v')
coherence = cm.get_coherence()
```